# RegEx for phone number pattern

Tags: javascript

The below is a snippet

```
<form name="form1" method="post" action="index_1.php" enctype="multipart/form-data"><br />
Mobile :&nbsp;&nbsp; <input name="Mobile" id="Mobile" type="text"><br><br>
<center><input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="javascript:return validateMyForm();"/></center>
</form>
```

and for validation, the JS is

```
function validateMyForm ( ) { 
    var isValid = true;
if ( document.form1.Mobile.value == "" ) { 
                alert ( "Please enter your mobile number" ); 
                isValid = false;
        }
            return isValid;
    }
```

How do I validate with a criteria like this **" /^(+91-|+91|0)?\d{10}$/" "** ???

Comment: possible duplicate of [A comprehensive regex for phone number validation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/123559/a-comprehensive-regex-for-phone-number-validation)

Comment: This is country dependent. Along with post code (zip codes for the yank audience)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
var val = number.value
if (/^(+91-|+91|0)?\d{10}$/.test(val)) {
   // value is ok, use it
}
```

Comment: + in regex is one or more characters. ( is a start of a regex to be passed on. The regex will not compile

Answer (score 0):

You can use a PHP [preg_match](http://pk1.php.net/preg_match) function, below is an example:

```
$phone = '+92-0000-0000';

if(preg_match("/^(+91-|+91|0)?\d{10}$/", $phone)) {
// $phone is valid
}
```

For more explanation see the link: 
[Validate Email Address and Phone Number](http://plasticbrain.net/resources/php-validate-email-address-and-phone-number/)

*For your code it would be like this:

```
$phone = document.form1.Mobile.value;

if (preg_match("/^(+91-|+91|0)?\d{10}$/", $phone)) { 

        isValid = true;
}
```

Comment: i'm kinda new to form building, could u explain how to use this with reference to the validation i've shown above... :)